# DispatcherTimer loses time while I'm dragging its Window

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I'm trying to build a simple timeout with C# WPF.

```
public void start(){
    answerTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    answerTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(answerTimer_Tick);
    answerTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,10);
    answerTimer.Start();
}

private void answerTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

This works but if I move the Window dragging it, the countdown stops and restart when I drop the Window....  how to avoid it?
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean in "I move the Window dragging it"

Comment: Like drag and drop: when I move the Application Window the countdown stops for a few.

Comment: Do you realize that you set the timer interval to 10 milliseconds? Are you really expecting the Tick handler to be called 100 timer per second? Set a sensible interval, e.g. 200 ms.

Comment: I know, this was just for test purpose. I also tried 100ms or 1s, but I get the same problem. With safi answer I solved. Thanks

Comment: i suggest to use `BackgroundWorker` instead of `DispatcherTimer` because it's smoother and run on diffrent `Thread`

Comment: Ok, but if I'm right I can not directly control Window components (label, textbox...) because they are in a different thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to put this

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Render);
```